# Flutter cannot connect to AWS with Web Socket Channel

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, websocket

I'm writing a program that required connecting to a Web Server using the Web Socket Channel package. I am following the guide https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/web-sockets to connect to an AWS Server. The link is something like this:

```
wss://xxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev/
```

Using the package I was able to connect and get the connectionState.waiting, but I cannot seem to listen to any data from the server nor send data to the server. For the data send, the format is below:

```
Map message = {
      "action": 'subscribe',
      "channel": 'contentTest',
    };
channel.sink.add(jsonEncode(message));
```

The rest of my code is similar to the guide, however the server does not seem to receive any data and neither can my client. Can anyone share a working example for above problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have a working example to share, you can see how the connection is done and the message is sent, this example is using the WebSocket class in dart:io. When I was coding this I had some issues with Web Socket Channel, can't remember why, so I opted for Dart WebSocket class.

```
 Future<WatchResponse> WatchCollection(
      CollectionRequest collectionRequest, String token) async {
    try {
      WebSocket ws = await WebSocket.connect(
          "ws://${this.authority}/gapi/collection/watch?token=$token");
      if (ws.readyState == WebSocket.open) {
        ws.add(jsonEncode(collectionRequest.toMap()));
        return WatchResponse(ok: true, streamSubscription: ws.listen(null));
      }
    } on WebSocketException catch (err) {
      return WatchResponse(ok: false, webSocketExecption: err);
    }
    return WatchResponse(ok: false, webSocketExecption: null);
  }
```